# DOM - links for page not available on one machine, are on another

Tags: dom, powershell, automation, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell to grab data from a website using DOM/IE.  It works fine on my desktop.  On my laptop, it fails. These are company configured machines with the same version of IE, same settings, same proxy, etc.  I looked at the security settings in IE, and they look the same.

This is the code that is returning no links even though there are links on the page:

```
$Links = $doc.Links
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you've confirmed the same set up on both machines, can you can navigate using a web browser (i.e IE)? If so, then it could be a timing issue? Try the code below which should wait for the page to finish loading before it grabs a handle to the DOM.

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.silent = $false
$ie.navigate2("http://google.co.uk")

while($ie.busy) { start-sleep 1 }

$doc = $ie.Document

$doc.links | Select innerText, href

$ie.Quit()
```

Comment: I do have a $ie.busy wait in my script. I ran your script. On my desktop, I get all kidns of output. On my laptop, I get nothing (though it definitely opens the browser and goes to that site when I set visible=true).

Comment: does $doc.fileSize return a size, (109264 on my machine)?

Comment: Do you get anything back using this...

`$webClient = new-object System.Net.WebClient <linebreak>
$webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "PowerShell Script") <linebreak>
$output = $webClient.DownloadString("http://www.google.co.uk/") <linebreak>

$output.Length <linebreak>`

Comment: Ignore my last comment. You get the page back via the IE object. Can you use PowerShell ISE and check what the $ie object returns? Also if the document object returns anything?

Comment: You are ont he right path...both ie and doc are empty. I don't know why though. I don't see anything that would cause that. It works fine up to that point. Up to that point, it logs into the site, goes to a certain page, selects a drop down list menu and then ie and doc are empty.

Comment: And, as I said, works fine on my other machine. I checked and the IE is the exact same version too. The Windows Patches I'm sure are different.  That could affect it.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere, I think! So it sounds like you are navigating to a site, selecting a drop-down then navigating to a second page. Does the first page return a DOM object you can see has content? Can you post the page and script you're trying to use (or an anonymised version of)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25855/discussion-between-user1921849-and-techspud)

Comment: Hi. Sorry, can't access chat on work machine. Might have time to pick this in the evening